# Cannot find file when using fswatch and rsync to automatically sync directories

Tags: bash, shell, rsync, fswatch

I am using fswatch and rsync to automatically sync directories between Mac and ubuntu servers.
The shell is like

/Users/david/Documents/code/shell/fswatch_rsync.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo fswatch -o /Users/david/Documents/code/python/ | xargs -n1 /Users/david/Documents/code/shell/rsync_shell.sh
```

/Users/david/Documents/code/shell/rsync_shell.sh:

```
sudo rsync -vzrp --delete /Users/david/Documents/code/python/ --password-file=/etc/rsyncd.pass -e "ssh -i /Users/david/.ssh/id_rsa -p 22" 192.168.0.109::python
```

However, when I run `bash /Users/david/Documents/code/shell/fswatch_rsync.sh` in terminal and change the files in `/Users/david/Documents/code/python/`, it responses:

```
xargs: ‎⁨/Users/david/Documents/code/shell/rsync_shell.sh: No such file or directory
```

in the terminal.

Comment: what does `ls -l /Users/david/Documents/code/shell/rsync_shell.sh` display?

Comment: Maybe it needs a `#!` at the top of the second script?

Comment: @jhnc, it returns
-rw-r--r--  1 david  staff  122  2 26 16:32 /Users/david/Documents/code/shell/rsync_shell.sh

Comment: try adding a semi-colon at the end of the line: `.../rsync_shell.sh;`

Comment: When I change /Users/david/Documents/code/shell/fswatch_rsync.sh like
```#!/bin/bash
sudo fswatch -o /Users/david/Documents/code/python/ | xargs -n1 sudo bash ./rsync_shell.sh
```
, run the shell after changing the working directory by
```cd /Users/david/Documents/code/shell/``` 
in terminal and finally it works. Therefore I think it should be some problems with the running path of the shell.

Comment: Glad you've found an answer. I suspect the underlying cause of the problem is that `rsync_shell.sh` is not executable. `chmod +x` should fix that. Another potential problem (possibly not in this case) is that if the line ends with `\r` instead of `\n`, bash can misinterpret the `\r` as part of the command (hence my suggestion to append a semi-colon).